# Passing id and as a parameter to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

http://jsfiddle.net/mato75/t48qn/

I have a directive, that if id is not passed, then it should generate one, but it looks like that the generation is to slow and the id is not present in the directive.

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

angular.module('Widgets.Module')
.directive('myDirective', [
    function () {
        function postLink(scope, jqElm, attr) { }

        function postCompile(tElement, tAttrs) {
            return function postLink(scope, jqElm, attr) {
                attr.$observe("id", function (id) { // called on on init
                    scope.id = id !== undefined ? id : 'something 1';
                });
            }
        }

        function Ctrl(scope) {
        }

        return {
            template:
                '<div id="{{ id }}">' +
                '</div>',
            controller: [
                '$scope', Ctrl
            ],
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                id: '@'
            },
            restrict: 'AC',
            link: postLink,
            compile: postCompile
        };

    }
])
;
})(window.angular)
```

Comment: I am not sure what the question is.  Can you go into more detail?

Answer (score 1):

I think using `id` is special since its a valid DOM attribute. In my case `id` was also getting added as an attribute to the directive html, not the inner child where I was using it.

I created a new attribute called `input-id` that doesn't suffer from this name collision.

```
<autosuggest input-id="country"></autosuggest>
```

The produced markup is:

```
<div class="autosuggest"><input id="country"></div>
```

...which is what I think you are after.

The `scope` block for the directive looks like this:

```
scope: {
    inputId: '@'
}
```

Comment: I was able to get this working using 'id', though you can name it whatever you want. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to disable the automatic data binding (`scope: {}`) and do it manually in your link function.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9UWQ/1/).

```
module.directive('myDialog', function () {
  return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    template: '<div>Test {{a1}}</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      if (!attrs.a1) {
        scope.a1 = "default";
      } else {
        scope.a1 = attrs.a1;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: no it does not work if I dont specify id in the scope, because then if the directive is used multiple times, the id will be

html
<directive id="dadada">
<directive>
<directive>

the first directive will look like this, when the html is compiled,
<directive id="dadada dadada dadada">

Comment: for me it works (take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/z9UWQ/2/. When I use `<my-dialog a1="111222"></my-dialog><my-dialog></my-dialog><my-dialog></my-dialog>` it compiles to `<div a1="111222" class="ng-binding">Test 111222</div><div class="ng-binding">Test default</div><div class="ng-binding">Test default</div>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z9UWQ/2/ - use a1 as an attribute in the element, , because I will use id as an attribute and a value.

Maybe that sounds strange, but I dont want to create like my-id attr

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve. Add a concrete sample to your question.